# some line of code not getting executed, when doing facebook post functionality

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

guys i am want to post on facebook, for that using facebook sdk, but some line of code not executed. is pops-up a dialog for login, when i do login, then `SessionEvents.AuthListener listener` should listen for login success. but its not listening. and every time when i start app it ask for login.
below is my code.

```
public class FacebookConnector {
private Facebook mFacebook;
private AuthListener mSessionListener;
private Context context;
private String[] permissions;
private Activity activity;

public FacebookConnector(String appId, Activity activity, Context context, String[] permissions) {

    this.mFacebook = new Facebook(appId);
    SessionStore.restore(mFacebook, context);
    SessionEvents.addAuthListener(mSessionListener);
    SessionEvents.addLogoutListener((LogoutListener) mSessionListener);
    this.context = context;
    this.permissions = permissions;
    this.activity = activity;

}

public void postMessageOnWall(String msg) {
    if (mFacebook.isSessionValid()) {
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("message", msg);
        try {
            String response = mFacebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
            System.out.println(response);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        login();
    }
}

public void login() {
    if (!mFacebook.isSessionValid()) {
        mFacebook.authorize(this.activity, this.permissions, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());
    }
}

public Facebook getFacebook() {
    return mFacebook;
}
}
```

and in my activity Class....

```
private void onFacebookBtnClicked() {
    if (facebookConnector.getFacebook().isSessionValid()) {
        postMessageInThread();
    } else {
        SessionEvents.AuthListener listener = new SessionEvents.AuthListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthSucceed() {
                postMessageInThread();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthFail(String error) {

            }
        };
        SessionEvents.addAuthListener(listener);
        facebookConnector.login();
    }
}
private void postMessageInThread() {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                facebookConnector.postMessageOnWall(mQuote.getQuoteText() + "\n" + mQuote.getAuthorName());
                mFacebookHandler.post(mUpdateFacebookNotification);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("Facebook", "Error sending msg", ex);
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
}

final Runnable mUpdateFacebookNotification = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Facebook updated !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
```

in that `postMessageInThread` method not executing, don't know why

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using? I suggest you to move to the 3.0 version.

Answer (score 1):

set this permission as public

```
private String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[]

    { "publish_stream", "read_stream", "offline_access" };
```

This will check is session exist if yes then it will direct update if not then ask user permission to update on wall.

Comment: even none of LoginDialogListener's methods are being called

Answer (score 1):

Hi friends i got the solution, for my problem, so now posting the answer. i just had to override`onActivityResult`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    mFacebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

i just added it and got my app working correctly.